# Opening non-express VS projects with Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-express

Is it possible to open / edit a normal Visual Studio Solution with Visual Studio Express Edition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible with restrictions (not all project types are supported).
You must edit the second line of sln-File.
For example change "**# Visual Studio 2010**"  to  "**# Visual C# Express 2010**"
This works for example for class libs or Windows Forms applications.

Comment: Thanks, that is exact, what I want to know !

Answer (score 5):

It depends. If this *normal* solution includes a unit testing project for example or a load tests or a modeling project (architecture, UML), then the answer is **no**. Class libraries, console applications, WinForm, ASP.NET, ... should be ok.