# Visual Studio 2010 vs Visual Studio 2010 Express share solution file and entity model

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to open a solution saved by VS 2010 Professional in Visual Studio Express and vice versa?

If so, will there be issues with the entity model (edmx)? I see the following statement here:

Visual Studio Express Editions cannot connect to a server. They can only connect to a file instance of a database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399247.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/visual-studio-2010-express?