# Visual C# Express 2010 Importing a project from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to load a project in my installation of Visual C# 2010 Express. The project was created by another groupmate using Visual Studio 2010. It's a stub project (no actual code). When I try to load it, I get the "[The project type is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation)" error, and the above SO solution didn't help because I don't know think Express has the command line thing. I tried [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/visual-studio-2010-express) but it didn't help me at all.

How can I get the project to load?

P.S. There's no complicated unit-testing in the project. It's literally a stub with no important code in it.

**Edit:** Here is a csproj file, as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{C1F8CC60-8F0A-4BAA-BC5B-B3603F662F26}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Team10BuyerSeller</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Team10BuyerSeller</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Default.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Login.aspx" />
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\BuyerSellerService.disco" />
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\configuration91.svcinfo" />
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\configuration.svcinfo" />
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\Reference.svcmap">
      <Generator>WCF Proxy Generator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Reference.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\Team10BuyerSeller.BuyerSellerService.CompositeType.datasource">
      <DependentUpon>Reference.svcmap</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Login.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Login.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Login.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Login.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\Reference.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Reference.svcmap</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\BuyerSellerService.wsdl" />
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\BuyerSellerService.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\BuyerSellerService1.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Service References\BuyerSellerService\BuyerSellerService2.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>53868</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>
          </IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

(this is the file I was given (just did `git reset HEAD --hard`). I did try swapping ProjectGuid as suggested, though.

Comment: Can you post the XML code from the project file (csproj)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project guid types suggest this project is a C# Web Application. If you have installed Visual C# Express is possible it will not open a project of type Web Application.

Try installing [Visual Web Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) instead.

Answer (score 1):

VS Express doesn't support unit test projects. If you want to load this project you shour change ProjectGuid value in .csproj file to {C1F8CC60-8F0A-4BAA-BC5B-B3603F662F26}

You may also install some plugins for VS to run tests.

Comment: I went into the .csproj file and changed my Guid to the value you suggested, but this didn't change anything... Are there any details missing? Possibly anything "obvious" but omitted?

Comment: You should also remove ProjectTypeGuids tag. VS uses it to determine type of a projec, eg web project, unit test project etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SP1 installed?  The behavior of the express editions, at least to me, appear to be better after SP1.  So you have tried to open just the project file, not the solution?  What type of project was originally used to create the stub code?  It may make a difference to the express edition.