# Compile a Solution in VS Express which was written in VS Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, visual-studio-express

I'm wanting to perform some maintenance on a C# project created in Visual Studio 2008 Professional.  I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Are there any pitfalls/limitation in opening the solution, converting the solution to VS '10 Express, compiling, and publishing with ClickOnce?

I've converted the solution, and all seems fine.  But I want to make sure of a few things:

Will VS warn me if the original solution contains projects that cannot be converted/compiled? I know that VS Express can't create Unit Test / Load Test and some other projects (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682357/470879)).  But what happens to these parts of the solution?  Am I potentially limiting the solution by loading it up in VS Express?  If the solution is reopened in VS Pro later, will those Load Tests, etc load up?

Comment: Make sure you have a backup, and try it!

Comment: Thanks, I have done so.  But because I'm unaware of whether the solution had these other types of projects included (unit tests, etc) before I tried it, I'm unsure of whether VS Express just ignored them, and whether I've inadvertently removed them from the solution by opening it.  Would VS Express warn me if it were doing such a thing?

Comment: So... compare the new project file with the original one. They're just text (XML) files.

Comment: I compared the two solution files, before and after, and everything looks good.  Thanks for your help, this was an easy way of checking that VS Express hadn't removed any of the unsupported projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you received no errors when converting the project you are safe.

Comment: And if I do get errors? (hypothetically). Would this means that I've limited the solution?  Would re-opening in VS Pro restore unlimit it again?

Comment: what do you mean by "limited the solution"?

Comment: VS Express won't compile certain project types that are part of the original solution right?  So I'm interested in what it does with them.  Will it remove them ('limiting' the solution)? What happens if this solution is then compiled in VS Pro again?

Comment: The projects stay in the solution, they are not loaded. This is a problem if you need to build them. Also you have a problem because you will not be able to open the updated solution in a previous VS version.