# compiling issue in old projectmade in vs 2010

Tags: c++

i have a project which is made in vs 2010. i have vs 2010 express. when i tried to open solution file of the project it give me an error that "not a valid project". while in back ground vs start loading project. when i build the project it give me errors that atlconv.h not found no such file or directory. please help me with this. Also when i open solution file in note pad, the follwong lines are mentioned 
"Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00 #Visual Studio 2010"

also vs2010 express says that .vcxproject is not a valid file.

Comment: Check include files location is specified. Check the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0f0a54c-5319-423a-b540-f4329db8cd68/compiler-errors-in-atlconvh-in-vc-mfc-program?forum=vcmfcatl)

Comment: For the link of post you provided, from it i infer i have to add additional directories is it correct? and also why vs2010 give error when i open .slu file?

Comment: Yes, point to the location, atlconv.h is located (if that directory not in the list). As for .SLN files, they might be incompatible, check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/opening-non-express-vs-projects-with-visual-studio-2010-express), it might help.

Comment: the project have openframework libraries included.i have tried the solution you provided but it is not working for .slu file

Comment: i have figure it out that express version dose not support mfc and atl type. So what version can support these type of file??

Comment: Right, MFC and ATL have never been included with the Express Editions Guess you should use Professional Edition