# Cannot open .csproj-file with Visual Studio C# 2010 Express

Tags: csproj, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm trying to open this project (https://github.com/shtejv/ARDrone-Control-.NET) downloaded from the internet but just when I open the project this error appears: "The project type is not supported by this installation."

It also shows the solution corresponding to that project as unavailable.

What can I do? maybe should I download a newer version of Visual Studio?

EDIT: The project that is causing the fail is called ARDrone_Testing so maybe it's a unit testing project so I'll need the full version of VisualStudio2010. I read it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/opening-non-express-vs-projects-with-visual-studio-2010-express)!

SOLUTION: It finally works properly, I've just finished installing vs2013 professional and open the project without any problem!
Thank you all!

Comment: ... maybe not try it with an express-edition? with .csproj-file fails? According to the dev, *This is a Visual Studio 2010 project using .NET framework 4.0* (plus some additional specs, like DirectX...)

Comment: Did you try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/opening-non-express-vs-projects-with-visual-studio-2010-express)?

Comment: Trying this approach I've read this " It depends. If this normal solution includes a unit testing project for example or a load tests or a modeling project (architecture, UML), then the answer is no. ". I don't know what a unit testing project is, but the project which is failing is called ARDrone_Testing so I supose that the real problem was that, what do you think?

Comment: Please add this crucial information to your question and not as a comment - but yes, I think that is the reason for the failed loading of the *ARDrone_Testing*  project.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, I'll check it in 3 days when Microsoft fixes my license!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the .sln file and it is created with Visual Studio 2010:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

What project is failing? (the name of the project)
Additional dependencies like DirectX shouldn't affect the project loading.

Comment: The name of the project is ARDrone_Testing so I think the problem is that I need the full version and not the Express of VS2010. I don't know what a unit project is but I think that this project is one of those so I would need to install the full version. I read it in this post, what do you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682308/opening-non-express-vs-projects-with-visual-studio-2010-express

Comment: Oh..most likely the project contains unit tests and the express version doesn't have this feature. Anyways you can discard unit test if you only want to see how that project work. If you want to write code for that project, most likely you'll need to write unit tests and you'll be unable without a non-express version of visual studio.